# Using dune + qtest in a multi-file project

Tags: unit-testing, ocaml, ocaml-dune

Let me begin by saying that I'm a complete beginner in OCaml, so if I seem to have made some weird choices, I'm most likely not aware of them being a choice.

I am trying to get unit testing working in my project. After some searching I settled on `qtest.lib`.

I've set up my project as follows:

```
$ mkdir mylib
$ cd mylib
$ dune init lib mylib
```

In the `dune` file, I've written:

```
(library
 (name mylib)
 (inline_tests (backend qtest.lib)))
```

In `mylib.ml`, I've put the following code:

```ml
let foo x = x + 2

(*$T foo
  foo 2 = 4
*)
```

At this point, *everything works as expected*:

```
$ dune runtest
Info: Creating file dune-project with this contents:
| (lang dune 2.9)
inline_test_runner_mylib alias runtest
random seed: 425752161
 [1 / 1] >foo>mylib.ml:4 *
 [1 / 1] >foo>;32;1mSUCCESS
```

The issues start if I try to introduce another file into the project. I created `helper.ml` with the following contents:

```ml
let bar x = 3 * x

(*$T bar
  bar 3 = 9
*)
```

Now, `dune runtest` errors out with

```
$ dune runtest
File "mylib.ml", line 11, characters 5-11:
Error: Unbound module Helper
```

In some of my other attempts at reproducing it, the file mentioned was instead `_build/default/.mylib.inline-tests/inline_test_runner_mylib.ml-gen`.

I first assumed that this means I'm organizing my files incorrectly. However, I can access `Helper.bar` within `mylib.ml`:

```
$ cat mylib.ml
let foo x = Helper.bar (x + 2)
$ dune build     # no errors
```

Thus I have no idea what the problem could be here. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Dune wraps library by default in a module with the same name as the library. For instance, defining a `mylib` library with

```
a.ml
b.ml
```

will create a `Mylib` module with `A` and `B` as submodule.
However, if you define a `mylib` module by hand, dune consider that this module is the entry point of your library, and it is your responsibility to expose all visible submodule.
Thus if you define `mylib.ml` as:

```
let x = 0
```

you are explicitly hiding the `Helper` module.
The simpler option here is probably to rename the `Mylib` module.

Another issue is that the qtest backend does not seem aware of dune wrapping libraries. A potential workaround is to define your own inline test backend and add an `open Mylib` to the preamble

```
(library (name myqtest)
 (modules)
 (inline_tests.backend
  (runner_libraries qcheck ounit2 bytes)
  (generate_runner (run qtest extract --preamble "open Myib" --quiet  %{impl-files} %{intf-files}))
 )
)

(library (name mylib) 
 (inline_tests
  (backend myqtest)
 )
)
```

(I hope that I am missing an option and that there is a simpler solution to send a flag to the runner generator)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it looks like you need to put

```
(modules)
```

in your dune file (as you can see [here](https://github.com/vincent-hugot/qtest/blob/master/src/dune))

Your dune file will look like:

```
(library
 (name mylib)
 (modules)
 (inline_tests (backend qtest.lib)))
```

Comment: Putting `(modules)` indeed gets rid of the error, but then the tests don't get run. `(modules mylib helper)` results in behavior identical to the one I described before.